# Convert prc-file (3D PDF) to 2D file format

Tags: 3d, conversion

I have a question regarding 3D PDF files.

I have a 3D vector graphics image which is saved as a Product Representation Compact (PRC) file. The PRC file is embedded in a PDF file. I can view and rotate the 3D image in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and it looks beautiful.

Now, I need to save this image in a 2D file format. In other words, I need to export the view of the 3D image as it appears in Acrobat Reader (from a given point of view) to a 2D file format. The file format could be either bitmap or vector graphics, it is not too important. For instance, I would like to save the image in a PNG- or SVG-file.

I have to do this because I need the image to be displayed in a graphical user interface (GUI) of a software I am working on. I work in a software company, an the GUI programmers would like me to hand over the image in a 2D file format like PNG or SVG.

I have tried several approaches to export the view from Acrobat Reader to a 2D file format, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution. I have tried to export the 3D PDF-file to JPEG and PNG using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. However, the pictures obtained with this method were extremely blurred. I have also tried to print the 3D graphics using the Adobe PDF printer, but this also yields poor results.

The only work around I have come up with so far is to make a screen shot when the graphics is shown in Acrobat Reader. This actually works, and I can get a PNG-file, but only at a relatively low solution. In any case, this is hardly a satisfactory solution.

My question is: Is there some way that I can obtain a high quality 2D file format from the 3D PDF (PRC-file) format?

Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be a screenshot, or if you want a higher resolution, print directly to PNG. Perhaps with something like: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/ I've never used it before, but it seems to get pretty good reviews. And it's open source.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have installed the PDFcreator virtual printer, as you suggested. I have tried to print the 3D PDF directly to PNG, and it works well. The only drawback is that I have to give the 3D PDF image very large dimensions (height and width) to obtain a high resolution of the print. But it does work, and it allows me to obtain the PNG-images that I want.